# Email wont send using the cpanel python app

Tags: python, email, module, cpanel, contact-form

I'm trying to use the cpanel python app for my python application due to domain issues on my NGINX server.

I have set up the python app and installed all the modules to run the app. The application runs fine, but on the contact page when i try send the contact form information i get a 500 internal server error.

The code worked perfectly fine on the NGINX server. i did have to change a few things to get the code to run on the python app in cpanel but it was just the passenger_wsgi.py file and app.run in my main.py file

Here is my code for app.py (main python file)

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
from forms import ContactForm

mail = Mail()

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = os.urandom(32)
app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "mail.example.com"
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 25
app.config["MAIL_USE_SSL"] = False
app.config["MAIL_USE_TLS"] = False
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = 'info@exmple.com'
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = 'example'

mail.init_app(app)
application = app

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.jinja2')


@app.route('/contact_us', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact_us():
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender=form.email.data, recipients=['info@example.com'])
        msg.body = """
              From: %s 
              Company Name: %s
              Message: %s
              """ % (form.full_name.data, form.company.data, form.message.data)
        mail.send(msg)

        return render_template('contact_us.jinja2', success=True, form=form)

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('contact_us.jinja2', form=form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is the form.py code

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email


class ContactForm(Form):
    full_name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired('Please add your name')])
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired('Please enter your email'), Email('Please enter a valid email')])
    subject = StringField('Subject', validators=[DataRequired('Please enter the subject of this email')])
    company = StringField('Company', validators=[DataRequired('Please enter your company name')])
    message = TextAreaField('message', validators=[DataRequired('Please enter a message')])
    submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

This is the form on the contact us page

```
<div class="card-body form">
                        {% if success %}
                            <p class="lead text-success">Thank you for feedback !</p>
                        {% endif %}
                        <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('contact_us') }}">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                        {% for error in form.full_name.errors %}
                                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        {{ form.full_name(class='form-control', id='form-contact-name') }}
                                        {{ form.full_name.label(for='form-contact-name') }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                        {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        {{ form.email(class='form-control', id='form-contact-email') }}
                                        {{ form.email.label(for='form-contact-email') }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                        {% for error in form.company.errors %}
                                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        {{ form.company(class='form-control', id='form-contact-company') }}
                                        {{ form.company.label(for='form-contact-company') }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                        {% for error in form.subject.errors %}
                                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        {{ form.subject(class='form-control', id='form-contact-subject') }}
                                        {{ form.subject.label(for='form-contact-subject') }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                        {% for error in form.message.errors %}
                                            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        {{ form.message(class='form-control md-textarea', id='form-contact-message') }}
                                        {{ form.message.label(for='form-contact-message') }}
                                        <div class="text-center text-md-left">
                                            {{ form.submit(class='btn btn-sm rounded btn-primary') }}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

I changed the email and password to example. There are no Error logs or codes, only gives me a 500 Internal server error after the send button is clicked. Else everything else about the app loads perfectly fine.

If there is any documentation about this problem would be great. I've been googling for about 4 days now not being able to find any solid information about the problem or how to get it working.

Comment: Add the traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure out the issue, Cpanel was not allowing the user form.email.data to be the sender. So i had to change it to the actual sender email being info@example.com. With that i added a reply-to so you can reply to the client.

I also had to change the configuration

```
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "Long Secret Key"
app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "mail.example.com"
app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 25
app.config["MAIL_USE_SSL"] = False
app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = 'info@example.com'
app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = 'password'

@app.route('/contact_us', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact_us():
    form = ContactForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender=("Contact Form", "info@example.com"), recipients=['info@example.com'], reply_to=form.email.data)
        msg.body = """
              From: %s
              Email: %s
              Company Name: %s
              Message: %s
              """ % (form.full_name.data, form.email.data, form.company.data, form.message.data)
        mail.send(msg)

        return render_template('contact_us.jinja2', success=True, form=form)

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('contact_us.jinja2', form=form)
```